# Don't understand what return does in pseudo code

Tags: pseudocode, a-star

I am trying to add A* path finding in a game I'm making.  I understand how to do it now but I don't understand what the returns do. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) is the reference that I'm using. Questions:

- What does `return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)` do?
- When is `return failure` invoked?

Comment: please provide source code

Comment: if you dont understand the algorithm why don't you choose another source as wikipedia

Comment: Source code is about 30ish lines long. I figured out the first part of my question. In adobe director I have to do "myvariable = myhandler(data)" with a return in the myhandler. My only question now is what does "Return failure" do? There is no variable or function named "failure" in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the function from your Wikipedia link:

```
function reconstruct_path(came_from, current_node)
    if current_node in came_from
        p := reconstruct_path(came_from, came_from[current_node])
        return (p + current_node)
    else
        return current_node
```

`return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)` calls this function.  The first `if` recursively calls `reconstruct_path`, each time with a different `current_node`, until the `current_node` is not in `came_from` (until the if fails).  Each time it calls itself, it returns `p := p + current_node`.  `p` keeps getting added to with each call, making `p` into a chain of nodes.

The thing that it's traversing, `came_from`, is some map.  It might look something like this:

```
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
```

Calling `came_from[1]` would return 2.  Or, you could say, "2 came from 1".

In short:  `reconstruct_path` calls itself, each time walking a step back in the map `came_from`, until it's build a path `p`.  This might look like, "1, 2, 3, 4", sticking with the example above.

`return failure` is called when a path cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I figured out how to implement it but still didn't really understand what the function did exactly.

Comment: The `came_from` map keeps track of where you've been in the graph.  `reconstruct_path` walks through it backwards to build that path.  By using recursion, it manages to build a path that goes from start->finish instead of finish->start.  Does that help?

Comment: yes it helps a lot. thank you. Only thing I don't understand now is the "return failure" part. is that just to end the script?

Comment: If it is able to find a path, then the path is returned.  `return failure` is called when no suitable path is found.

Answer (score 0):

Generically, `return function()` first evaluates the `function()` on stack and then whatever the function returns is returned by the parent/calling function.

In your case, `return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)` will evaluate `reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)` and return *that* value back.

EDIT:

For instance-

```
A(){
  print(B());
}

B(){
  return 10;
}
```

This is a more 'static' example of how return works. Here, `A()` is the calling function and `B()` is the called function. The value being returned is `10` in this case. Moving on, in your problem, `return f()` first calls `f()`. `f()` has a `return` within it and returns a value- say `10`. Then whatever `f()` evaluates into, is sent back to the original callee function.

Comment: The scripting style I use is old and quite different than most. I've never had to use returns, i use global variables. My only question now is about the "return failure"

Comment: Am i more clear now? And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python) may help.

Answer (score 0):

`reconstruct_path` simply recursively returns the list of nodes the path consists from.